# Get info from a table on a website where XPATH varies on each site, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dom, xpath, lxml

If you take this website as an example:

http://gbgfotboll.se/information/?scr=table&ftid=51168

I am using this code to get information from the second table:

```
for url in urlList:

    request = net.Request(url)
    response = net.urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()

    dom = lxml.html.parse(BytesIO(data))
    #all table rows


    xpatheval = etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator(dom)
    rows = xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[2]/tbody/tr')

    divName = xpatheval('//*[@id="content-primary"]/h1//text()')[0]
    trash, divisionName = divName.rsplit("- ")

    dict[divisionName] = {}

    for id,row in enumerate(rows):
        columns = row.findall("td")

        teamName = columns[0].find("a").text, # Lag
        print teamName
        teamName
        playedGames = columns[1].text, # S
        wins = columns[2].text,
        draw = columns[3].text,
        lost = columns[4].text,
        dif = columns[6].text, # GM-IM
        points = columns[7].text, # P - last column 

        dict[divisionName].update({id :{"teamName":columns[0].find("a").text, "playedGames":playedGames, "wins":wins, "draw":draw, "lost":lost, "dif":dif, "points":points }})
```

For that website the **rows** has table[**2**]

For this website:

http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108

the rows would need to look like this:

```
rowss = '//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[1]/tbody/tr'[0]
```

So what I am asking for if there is a way to get the information I need regardless what table index the table will be at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to select by its `class` attribute (all 3 classes are required):

```
xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]/table[@class="clCommonGrid clTblStandings clTblWithFullToggle"]/tbody/tr'
```

An alternative would be to select a child element in that table that you know is only present in that specific type of table. For example, the `GM-IM` header could be quite specific to that type of table, so I navigate to it and then work my way up the tree to end up with the same rows as you:

```
xpatheval('//div[@id="content-primary"]//tr[th="GM-IM"]/../../tbody/tr')
```

Comment: Wow ur a genius, tried the second option since i was not sure if the class name was always the same. Lets assume the are the same, are there any speed differences between them?

Comment: @AppDev I didn't do any profiling on these approaches. However, I doubt that will be the bottleneck in your application, as you are still bandwidth-limited. I suggest not prematurely optimizing. However, if you are sure it is the bottleneck, consider running some `timeit` experiments.